# Exercise: Prove $\;L^2-$norm of a sequence of functions goes to $\;\infty\;$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $\;u,v:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m\;$ be two functions such that:
>   $\; \vert u(x)-l_{+} \vert \le e^{-kx}\;$,$\; \vert u(x)-l_{-} \vert \le e^{kx}\;;$ as $\ x  \to
>  +\infty\;$ and $\; x  \to
>  -\infty\;$ respectively. Similarly for $\;v\;$. (NOTE: $\;k \gt 0\;$ and $\;l_{-} \neq l_{+}\;$)
>
> If $\;y_n \in \mathbb R\;$ is a unbounded sequence, in the sense that
>   $\;y_n \to \infty\;$ as $\;n \to \infty\;$, and $\;{\vert
>  u(x)-v(x-y_n) \vert}^2 \to {\vert u(x) - l_{-} \vert}^2\;$ as $\;n \to \infty\;$, prove that
>   $\;\int_{\mathbb R} {\vert u(x)-v(x-y_n) \vert}^2 \;dx\to \infty\;$ as
>   $\;n \to \infty\;$

I observed that $\;\int_{\mathbb R} {\vert u(x)-l_{-} \vert}^2 \;dx\;=\infty\;$ but I can't see how to take advantage of this fact in order to show the $\;L^2-$norm of $\;u(x)-v(x-y_n) \;$ goes also to $\;\infty\;$.

Am I missing some crucial Theorem here?

I 'm having a really hard time getting my head around this so any help or even hints would be valuable!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you obtain $\int |u - l_-|^2 = \infty$?

Comment: @user251257 By Minkowski's inequality: $\;\vert \vert l_{+}-l_{-} \vert \vert \le \vert \vert l_{+}-u \vert \vert+\vert \vert u-l_{-} \vert \vert \;$

Comment: how could $|u(x) - l_{\pm}|\le e^{-k|x|}$ for $|x|\to\infty$ be true the same time?

Comment: @user251257 this means $\;\vert u(x)-l_{+} \vert \le e^{-kx}\;$ as $\;x \to +\infty\;$ and  $\;\vert u(x)-l_{-} \vert \le e^{kx}\;$ as $\;x \to -\infty\;$ ,but I'm not sure if this is what you asked

Comment: no it doesn't. You should update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n =|u(x)-v(x-y_n)|^{2}$ and $f_n =|u(x)-l_{-}|^{2}$. You have stated that $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $\int f= \infty$. By Fatou's Lemma $\infty = \int f = \int \liminf f_n \leq \liminf \int f_n$ so $\int f_n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the kind of answer I was hoping for. One last question: why are $/;f_n/; $ measurable? If I knew $/;u,v/; $ are continuous I would understand it, but now why?

Comment: $x \to v(x-y_n)$ is measurable because it is the composition of the continuous map $x \to x-y_n$ and v. Hence $u(x)-v(x-y_n)$ is also measurable. Finally, $t \to |t|^{2}$ is continuous, hence measurable, so $f_n$ is measurable.